# Removing an Object From a list

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I have declared declared a `std::list<MachineState*> zombs` in my

```
class CZombieView : public CWindowImpl<CZombieView>
{
public:


   CZombieView();
   void DrawGrid();
   Gdiplus::Bitmap m_BitmapImage;
   Gdiplus::Graphics m_GraphicsImage;

   MachineState zombieTestState;
   Machine<ZombieTraits> zombieMachine;
   MachineState zombieTestState2;
   MachineState zombieTestState3;


   Machine<HumanTraits>humanMachine;
   MachineState humanTestState;
   MachineState humanTestState2;
   MachineState humanTestState3;

   std::list<MachineState*> zombs;
   std::list<MachineState*> humans;
};
```

I have declared another class. Opp.cpp

```
class Op
{
 public:
   CZombieView * cz;
   MachineState * neighboor;
   MachineState * neighboor2;
   void setNeighboor(MachineState * decoy); //
   void setNeighboor2(MachineState * decoy2);
   virtual void Execute(MachineState& state) = 0;
 };
```

The setNeighboor function sets the zombieTestState of the CZombieView to the variable neighboor.  When i try to call `cz->zombs.remove(neighboor)` after the neighboor has already been set, i get exceptions and my call stack on visual studio points to the `const _Nodeptr _Phead = this->_Myhead;`...I'm not sure why this is happening, or if this is the wrong way to delete an object from a list...Any input would be appreciated

```
void Op::setNeighboor2(MachineState * decoy2)
{
     neighboor2 = decoy2;
    cz->zombs.remove(neighboor2);
    std::cout<<"SET";
}
```

My program halts right at `cz->zombs.remove(neighboor2)` and the print statement doesn't even get printed.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the actual code that is giving an error.

Comment: @Xymostech I have added where my program halts...I don't know if that is of any help??

Comment: Looks like some sort of corruption. This will have happened somewhere else in your code because there's nothing wrong with `setNeighboor2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your cz has not been properly initialized.  That would account for the crash on first dereferencing it to obatin the zombs member and then calling a method on that.  You should set it to nullptr in Op's constructor, and examine the value when it crashes.